# C -comparing char with new line

Tags: c

I have one code where I want to check the number of rows in a file. The file has 6 rows. I try compare with new line '/n', but the result is not ok. Here is the code. Please help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE*code;
    int NumbRow = 0;
    char c;

    code = fopen("SMS.txt", "r");
    if(code==NULL)
    {
        printf("I cant read from file");
        return;
    }
again:
    while ((c=fgetc(code)) !=EOF)
    {
        if (c=='/n')
        {
            NumRow ++ ;
        }
        if (c!='/n')
        {
            goto again;
        }
    }
    printf ("Number of rows is : %d", NumRow);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. "But the result is not ok" is not a very precise problem statement.

Comment: What's with the `goto`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `'\n'` instead of `'/n'` in your code. `'\n'` moves you to the next line.

Comment: ... and check if your compiler can warn for character literals with more than one character (`'/n'` has two, but `'\n'` is just one, the single newline character).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `'\n'` as a newline character but you are using `'/n'` that's not a newline character `'/n'` mean there is two character `'/'` and `'n'`.